What happened to my connecting wall?! (I suspect vowel play...)
Having devised some rather tricky connecting walls for you all in the past, I thought it was about time I made a nice, normal, easy one for a change. Just the standard basic rules - sixteen items, which need to be sorted into four groups of four based off their connecting properties.
I've picked four areas of trivia very commonly used in a typical pub quiz, nothing particularly obscure - I've even specified these four themes using the question tags, to point you towards them generously. Moreover, to leave you in no doubt at all about which items belong to which group, each item in the wall is a two-word entry, which should remove any tricksy ambiguities.
As per tradition, for presentation purposes I've arranged the entries alphabetically, and so without further ado here it i- OH NO! What's happened to my connecting wall?!











AU OE
UIA AO
EUAOIA UIEA
EOE AIO


O EO
EIEE I
AEE I
AEE UIE


AU AE
EE A
IO A
OI OO


IEA EOE
EEI EAU
OU AIA
E AIOA



It seems that for some reason all of the consonants have completely disappeared, leaving just each occurrence of the 5 classical vowels: A, E, I, O and U! How could this have happened? And everything was looking so easy and straightforward...
But you can still solve this, right?
TASK: Resolve the connecting wall into four groups of four. Identify the group connections and the true identities of the group members once their consonants are replaced.

I have a feeling this was inspired by a recent connect wall puzzle on here!

@PDT Ha, actually no, not knowingly anyway - this idea came to me while I was trying to fall asleep last night! I had to scrabble about in the dark for a pen and paper and write it down immediately because I knew I would forget it otherwise...!

Scrabble? Interesting...

rot13(Tebhc 1 unf gb or Nsevpna pbhagevrf: 'RDHNGBEVNY THVARN, FBHGU NSEVPN, FVREEN YRBAR, naq OHEXVAN SNFB.')

@Stiv missed opportunity to use an interrobang in the title ;)

@sarsaparilla True :) A sadly underused punctuation mark, and I'm clearly doing nothing to help its cause! (Or am I‽)

@Stiv that last comment is a bit contrived, haha

Here's the completed grid:

 |BLACKBURN ROVERS|  BURKINA FASO  |EQUATORIAL GUINEA|  GEORGE HARRISON  |
 |     JOHN LENNON    |  LEICESTER CITY  |  MANCHESTER CITY  |MANCHESTER UNITED|
 |  PAUL MCCARTNEY  |      PETER PAN     |      RINGO STARR      |        ROBIN HOOD       |
 |     SIERRA LEONE     |SLEEPING BEAUTY|     SOUTH AFRICA     |    THE ARISTOCRATS   |

And these are the categories:

Premier League winners
BLACKBURN ROVERS, LEICESTER CITY, MANCHESTER CITY, MANCHESTER UNITED


African countries
BURKINA FASO, EQUATORIAL GUINEA, SIERRA LEONE, SOUTH AFRICA


The Beatles
GEORGE HARRISON, JOHN LENNON, PAUL MCCARTNEY, RINGO STARR


Disney movies
PETER PAN, ROBIN HOOD, SLEEPING BEAUTY, THE ARISTOCATS

My approach was to start with the entries with many vowels, keeping in mind the tags and alphabetization. I was able to guess EUAOIA UIEA and AEE UIE thanks to their associated tags and relative placement, then guess their categories to help with other answers. Guessing the first word of E AIOA helped solve it and its category. The last category was tricky, but with one tag remaining I was able to break into it by solving AU AE. In general, the categories and order were very useful clues.

Impressively quick! Can I ask what your break-in was? I'd be interested to know how you went about solving this... Thanks.

@Stiv IIRC my break-ins for each category were EUAOIA UIEA, AEE UIE, AU AE, and E AIOA. The rest become easier using the categories and alphabetization.

Interesting! The first two were the exact break-ins I hoped would allow the rest to follow (and the alphabetical order was retained as the only logic available to the solver). Particularly interested that E AIOA was so useful to you, as I'd thought EEI EAU would be the route for that category given its very narrow possible scope given its neighbours. Well, well done and thanks for the solve!

You’ve inserted one erroneous consonant in E AIOA, giving a very different result…

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Nice catch, thanks!

The checkmark will be coming your way, but could you maybe add a note to your answer about your break-in, so that readers might better understand how they could go about solving this one? The comment's getting a number of upvotes, suggesting that it's useful info to include. Thanks :)

@Stiv Agreed! I wish I had recorded my solve path instead of relying on my shaky recollection. Hopefully my summary suffices :)

@noedne Perfect - really helpful, thanks. Checkmark granted!
